# How add an Application Pre-loader/Startup screen/Splash Screen to My PhoneGap Android App

Tags: android, cordova

I have created a Android app using phone Gap.It works fine.How I add a pre-loader image to My App.Now it show a white page while loading the application.

Help is highly appreciated,
Thank,
VKS.

Answer (score 18):

If you mean pre-loader image has Splash screen refer the following code;

**For PhoneGap :**

```
public class MyDefaultActivity extends Activity {

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash); // Displays the splash screen for android
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html",3000); // Second parameter is duration for delay of splash screen
    }
}
```

**For Android Native app :**

```
public class MySplashScreen extends Activity {
    private CountDownTimer lTimer;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen); // Contains only an LinearLayout with backround as image drawable

        lTimer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
            public void onFinish() {
                closeScreen();
            }
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void closeScreen() {
        Intent lIntent = new Intent();
        lIntent.setClass(this, MyLauncherActivity.class);
        startActivity(lIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Make sure a file called `splash.png` is present as `res/drawable-hdpi/splash.png` (RGBA).

Comment: hi @Vinayak.B i want to ask if I have code for android webview application, but before the webview loaded completely i want to show my company logo image first.. I have write a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701179/how-to-change-background-image-on-android-progress-dialog   i really need your advise please, thankyou :)

Answer (score 4):

You could create an `AsyncTask` implementation for showing an image / progress indicator while your application's data is loading in the background thread.

1. In the async task's `onPreExecute`
   method you show the chosen preloader
   (image / ProgressDialog / etc)
2. in the `doInBackground` method you
   start loading the necessary data,
   and
3. in the `onPostExecute` method you
   remove/hide your preloader, so the
   activity's desired layout will be
   shown.

Answer (score 0):

If by preloader image you mean a low-resolution version of the big image, you can use a [VewSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html) with two ImageViews in it: one image view contains the preloader image, while the other contains the full image (while it's loaded). Initially, you make the preloaded image visible, but when the big Bitmap finishes loading you just use `switcher.showNext()` to show the full image.

Some further reading about the ViewSwitcher (the example does something similar): [here](http://inphamousdevelopment.wordpress.com/2010/10/11/using-a-viewswitcher-in-your-android-xml-layouts/)