# How I add a pre-loader image to My Android App

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How add an Application Pre-loader to My PhoneGap Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865697/how-add-an-application-pre-loader-to-my-phonegap-android-app)

Hi, I have created a Android app.It works fine.How I add a pre-loader image to My App.Now it show a white page while loading the application.

Help is highly appreciated, Thank, VKS.